# Segmentation fault when trying to import a box inside another box

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pygobject

I have a problem with my simple Python application that I'm trying to do. I want to import a box in an other other one. Which one is a class. It'll be more clear when you'll see my code I think :

```
class Logbook:

    def __init__(self):
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('openplane/gui/logbook/logbook.glade')

        self.window = builder.get_object('mainWindow')
        # On défini l'icône de la fenêtre
        self.window.set_icon_from_file(config.icon_path)

        # On récupère la grille où l'on va attacher les différents widgets
        grid = builder.get_object('layout')

        # On créer la vue des vols
        self.flight_view = FlightView()
        # Et on l'importe directement dans la grille
        grid.attach(self.flight_view, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

So I want to import the `FlightView` class in my `Logbook` window.

```
class FlightView(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self):
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('openplane/gui/logbook/flight_view.glade')

        # On récupère le layout principal qu'on attache ensuite à cette classe
        # celle-ci se fait ensuite attachée dans le logbook
        main_layout = builder.get_object('FlightView')
        self.pack_start(main_layout, True, True, 0)
```

Sorry for all the comments in french.

But I run this, I have the `Segmentation fault`. I read that I just can't avoid it with a simple catch. So why this error is raised with this simple code ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: There is no error traceback! I just have `Erreur de segmentation` which means `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: can you run a debugger line by line ?

Comment: pick a better title!

Comment: How? I don't have any Python debugger, I use Sublime Text.

Comment: Can you post a minimal (working) example? It would be much easier to help if it's reproducible